# What stops a site stealing another site's user's data with CORS?

Tags: cors

My understanding of CORS is that if a page requests data from a different domain, the browser will use the different domain's cookie for the browser user when making the request. Does this open up the possibility of the following security hole?

Let's say I'm running a.com with open CORS (accepting all requests). What is stopping b.com from making a request to a.com in JS to an endpoint that is secured (via cookie auth) and getting some info from the user's account on a.com and then uploading it to b.com all behind the scenes? If the browser includes the cookie, then the server has no way to know if it's the real user, or another site pretending to be the user.

Am I missing something here, or is this a possibility?

This assumes the current browser user has visited a.com, signed in to a.com, then later visited b.com

Answer (score 0):

> What is stopping b.com from making a request to a.com in JS to an endpoint that is secured (via cookie auth) and getting some info from the user's account on a.com and then uploading it to b.com all behind the scenes?

Nothing.

You are running with open CORS.

That means you are explicitly granting permission to any site to read the data that you are sending to the user's browser.

The point of the Same Origin Policy is to prevent that. CORS allows you to turn that security feature off.

Setting a completely open CORS allows any site to access the data you give the user. You should not set a completely open CORS when there is data that shouldn't be available to every site.